# Error after Xcode 6.3 update

Tags: xcode, xcode6.3

I am getting the following errror after I updated Xcode to 6.3. I cannot run the apps on simulator or on device. I didn't update the OS. Do I need to update the OS to 10.10.3 to get Xcode working?

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died)
```

Comment: I know this sounds condescending, but I mean it sincerely: did you try restarting Xcode? ~50% of the time that fixes warnings I don't understand.

Comment: Actually I would suggest restarting the whole darned computer. This is often necessary after an Xcode update, I find.

Comment: After restarting the computer it worked fine!!!